# Records from table not showing and not edible in AxGridView

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, enterprise-portal

Lets say that I want to show records from a table into an AxGridView and make that AxGrivView being able to create, edit and delete a record, are there any good tutorial on how to accomplish that?

**EDIT**

I'll try and explain what I've done so:
I've this dataset:

[image]

with these properties for eg. TrvExpParm_cars:

[image]

My user control contains this code:

```
<dynamics:AxColumn ID="TopRowRight" runat="server">
        <dynamics:AxMultiSection ID="AxMultiSection1" runat="server">
            <dynamics:AxSection ID="AxSection1" runat="server" Caption="Mine biler" Expanded="true">
                <dynamics:AxDataSource ID="dsEPTrvExpParm_cars" runat="server" DataSetName="EPTrvExpParm" ProviderView="TrvExpParm"> </dynamics:AxDataSource>

                <dynamics:AxGridView ID="AxGridView_cars" runat="server" 
                    AllowDelete="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowPaging="False" BodyHeight="" 
                    DataKeyNames="RecId" DataMember="TrvExpParm_cars" 
                    DataSetCachingKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
                    DataSourceID="dsEPTrvExpParm_cars" EnableModelValidation="True">
                    <Columns>
                        <dynamics:AxBoundField DataField="Name" DataSet="EPTrvExpParm" 
                            DataSetView="TrvExpParm_cars" SortExpression="Name">
                        </dynamics:AxBoundField>
                        <dynamics:AxBoundField DataField="LicensePlate" DataSet="EPTrvExpParm" 
                            DataSetView="TrvExpParm_cars" SortExpression="LicensePlate">
                        </dynamics:AxBoundField>
                    </Columns>
                </dynamics:AxGridView>

            </dynamics:AxSection>
        </dynamics:AxMultiSection>
    </dynamics:AxColumn>
```

What I get is an empty grid:

[image]

The table EPTrvExpParm_cars contains two fields with 2 records:

[image]

I really don't know why I can't see the data from the table. Are there some properties that I need to set or do I need som custom code? According to the Dynamics AX 2012 Enterprise Portal Cookbook, custom code shouldn't be needed, but again it's just a "cookbook"

**UPDATE**
The relation between TrvExpParm and TrvExpParm_cars is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the relation between your `TrvExpParm` and `TrvExpParm_cars`?

The way your datasource is defined the `TrvExpParm` is the data provider (providerview) so it will look for a `TrvExpParm` record (the first) and will try to show the linked `TrvExpParm_cars` records because in your gridview you choose `TrvExpParm_cars` as `DataSetView`.

Comment: I've updated my question with an image of the relation between those two tables

Comment: it looks a bit odd to have a relation on userId but this aside, is there data in the TrvExpParm table? Could it be that there are more than 1 records in the TrvExpParm table and the first record is not for user DENPMP?

Comment: So it seems that there wasn't a record in the table TrvExpParm with the userID DENPMP. That was the problem. No record with userId DENPMP. After creating a record with userID DENPMP, my records from TrvExpParm_cars showed up. Many thx for the help!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

The following whitepaper should help you do that: [Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 White Paper: Enterprise Portal Development Cookbook](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30171)

A quote from the document:

> AxGridView also includes built-in data modification capabilities. By using AxGridView with the declarative 
>   AxDataSource, you can easily configure and modify data without writing code. [...] AllowInsert, AllowEdit, and AllowDelete properties control the create, read, update, and delete operations on the grid.

Comment: I've been trying the example from the White paper, but I can't get data showing in the grid. With a simple table that contains two string fields, following the White paper only gives me the field names.